# tcp auto tuning is best for every circumstance?

Tags: sockets, http, memory, tcp, buffer

learned that kernel automatically set tcp rcv/snd buffer size with consideration of memory.. etc

1. The name 'tcp auto tuning' seemed that kernel seems to be the most appropriate to handle everything

Is there no need to set up a buffer size manually on very busy server?

2. and 'tcp auto tuning' make different buffer size for every socket creation??(regarding current internal or network states)

Comment: If you're asking these questions, you're better off letting the TCP stack handle the tuning and not trying to second-guess it -- the TCP algorithm has been worked on for decades by people who understand the issues very well.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner So you say i dont need custom configuration? Because tcp algorithm always covers every circumstance?

Comment: I’m saying that if you don’t have a specific reason for messing with things, that you’re better off leaving then alone.  Changing settings without a good understanding of what you are doing is a good way to make performance worse, not better.